# McNemar test comparing two proportions in a crossover trial

Tags: self-study, mcnemar-test, crossover-study

> In a crossover trial involving 50 patients, two dialysis treatment schedules were compared.Ten patients complained of vomiting on both schedules, 30 on neither, nine on treatment A only and one on treatment B.
>
> (a) What are the proportions of patients vomiting on each treatment?
>
> (b) Perform a significance test comparing these two proportions and interpret the results.

For (a), I think it is 19/50 and 11/50

For (b), I think I have to use McNemar test: (19-11)^2/(19+11)=2.31.

But I'm not sure, can you please check if my answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to check is to create the contingency table:
\begin{array}{rccl}
 &\text{treatment B} &\text{vomiting} &  \\
\text{treatment A vomiting }\ \ &{\rm yes} &{\rm no} &{\rm sum}  \\
{\rm yes} &10 &9 &?  \\
{\rm no} &1 &30 &31  \\
{\rm sum} &? &39 &  
\end{array}
An overview of McNemar's test, it's justification, and the formulas can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89415/7290), and below that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141450/7290).  (To provide a hint, your formula is incorrect.)

Comment: Can you make it the rest of the way yourself, now?

Comment: To add a hint for the general problem of paired binary data: concordant results are effectively thrown away with McNemars... our attention is only on discordant pairs (those on the off-diagonal of the contingency table).

Comment: Ou, so the right formula then is (9-1)^2/(9+1)=6.4>>3.84, which means that we should reject the null hypothesis. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, @Art. Good luck with your course.