# Which test to use for generalizations

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm currently conducting a research in linguistics. The goal is to show the audience preference when it comes to different translation strategies in subtitling. The experiment design has one independent variable with two levels (2 different translations of the same clip), and the dependent variable is the reception (like it, don't like it). The expected number of participant is 100. As I am a complete novice in statistics, which test would you suggest to use to make generalizations and test hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a 2x2 table as a result of the experiment. If each person in your sample sees only one version, you could use the chi-square test.

If you get the same 100 people watch both translations and rate them, you might use McNemar's test.

You could read more here: [What is the difference between McNemar's test and the chi-squared test, and how do you know when to use each?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76875/what-is-the-difference-between-mcnemars-test-and-the-chi-squared-test-and-how)