# Which test should I use to compare 2 unrelated dichotomous variables?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, binary-data

I have two variables, both of which are categorical and binary/dichotomous, and I need to determine if there is any 'correlation' between them. Note that I am using this term carefully, as I know 'correlation' technically measures the change in one variable, which is not applicable for categorical, dichotomous variables. I simply want to know if there is a link between my two sets of data.

One variable is whether a gene is a 'pseudogene' or not (1 for pseudogene, and 0 for non-pseudogene), and the other is whether the gene is a 'complement' gene or not (1 for complement, and 0 for non-complement).

An example of the data is as follows, where each row is a single gene (imagine this but on a scale of about 500,000 rows):

```
pseudo    complement 
   0          1
   0          0
   1          1
   0          1
   0          1 
   1          0
```

Many of my extensive Google searches have told me that, for two categorical variables, the chi-square test is appropriate. I've tried using this but my results don't seem to be very reliable - more research has told me that the context of my data is also not appropriate, as the test concerns comparing different populations, whilst my variables are unrelated. So chi-square is probably completely out of the ballpark.

Similarly, I see some suggestions that the phi coefficient test is designed for comparing 2 dichotomous variables - however it seems again that the context of the test is not appropriate for my data.

Which statistical test should I be using for testing any correlation/link between these two variables? (Bonus if you can tell me how to do this in R, but my main concern is just deciding which test is appropriate.)

Comment: If the rows could be considered a random sample, then the default choice would indeed be a chi-squared test of independence or Fisher's exact test. But since genes from same subject will depend on each other in a complex way, this won't do the job. Actually I doubt that a hypothesis test would be a good way to "quantify" the strenght of association in this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but it seems that your data can be exactly summarized in a $2 \times 2$ table of counts, and your notion of "correlation" is actually independence: whether
$$\Pr(\text{pseudo} = a, \text{complement} = b) = \Pr(\text{pseudo} = a) \Pr(\text{complement} = b)$$
for all $a, b \in \{0, 1\}$.

This is the setting of [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), to which what's called a chi-squared test is a pretty good approximation. With 500,000 samples, as long as your probabilities aren't incredibly skewed, they'll probably give exactly the same result, though a [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) is supposedly a better approximation.

> more research has told me that the context of my data is also not appropriate, as the test concerns comparing different populations, whilst my variables are unrelated. So chi-square is probably completely out of the ballpark.

One can use the test to compare different problems, but there's nothing in the formulation of the test that requires that; it's just a property of contingency tables, no matter how you arrive at the table.

> I see some suggestions that the phi coefficient test is designed for comparing 2 dichotomous variables

I'm not sure what you mean by "the phi coefficient test," but [the usual phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) is exactly the chi-squared test statistic divided by the sample size, so presumably it's the same as a chi-squared test.

Basically, chi-squared seems to be an appropriate test.

> I've tried using this but my results don't seem to be very reliable

What are you seeing that makes you think the chi squared test isn't reliable on your data?

Comment: The answer is helpful (+1) given the most straightforward interpretation of the question. The question, unfortunately, is a bit vague about the specific hypothesis being tested. As [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141450/28500) shows, a different type of hypothesis on the same 2 x 2 contingency table might require Mc Nemar's test instead.